# Converting string to arrayList using .add

Tags: string, arraylist, char

I am having trouble with my code.  I am trying to convert a String to a char ArrayList using the .add method for arraylists.  However I get the following error

The method add(int, String) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (int, char)

Can someone tell me where I've gone wrong with the code, or point me in the right direction?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Benford {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        //countDigits(123456);
        nthDigitBack(12,359938);
    }

    public static int countDigits(double inNum){
        double result = Math.log(inNum) / Math.log(10);
         result = (int) (Math.ceil(result));
         System.out.println(result);
        return (int) result;

    }
    public static int nthDigitBack(int n, int num){
        System.out.println(countDigits(num));

        //convert num to string
        String transferToArray = Integer.toString(num);
        //create character array
        ArrayList<String> charArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        //convert string to Array
        for(int i = 0; i < countDigits(num); i++){
            charArray.add(i, transferToArray.charAt(i));
        }


        return 1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an ArrayList that takes Strings:

```
ArrayList<String> charArray = new ArrayList<String>();
```

But you have called it charArray, and then you try to add chars to it. Either you should make your List into a List of Character (the wrapper around the primitive char) or change your add method to add String.

Option 1:

```
//create character array
ArrayList<Character> charArray = new ArrayList<Character>();
//convert string to Array
for(int i = 0; i < countDigits(num); i++){
    charArray.add(i, transferToArray.charAt(i));
}
```

Option 2:

```
//create character array
ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
//convert string to Array
for(int i = 0; i < countDigits(num); i++){
    stringArray.add(i, ""+transferToArray.charAt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in method nthDigitBack error occurred at

charArray.add(i, transferToArray.charAt(i));

as you are trying to add a Chracter datatype to a string array. you are only allowed to add String data type in charArray.

Change charArray to

```
ArrayList<Character> charArray = new ArrayList<Character>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following instead?

```
charArray.add(i, transferToArray.substring(i, i+1));
```